# Set a variable inside prerequisites or eval function

Tags: gnu-make

I have this code, and it works, but as you see I do the substitute three times, I would like to set a variable to the value, but with no success

```
$($(PKG)-py-valgrind-tests-status): $($(PKG)-swig-dlib)
$($(PKG)-py-valgrind-tests-status): $(OBJ_OUTPUT_DIR)%.valgrind_passed: %.py
@echo env $(PKG-TEST-HELPER-ENV) valgrind $(VALGRIND-FLAGS) --log-file=$(subst valgrind_passed,valgrind.log,$@)  $(PYTHON_BIN) $< -v ; \
env $(PKG-TEST-HELPER-ENV) $(VALGRIND) $(VALGRIND-FLAGS) --log-file=$(subst valgrind_passed,valgrind.log,$@)  $(PYTHON_BIN) $< -v \
                                                        || (cat $(subst valgrind_passed,valgrind.log,$@); exit 1)
@touch $@
```

the problematic line $(subst valgrind_passed,valgrind.log,$@)

I tried:

```
$($(PKG)-py-valgrind-tests-status): LOG-FILE = $(subst valgrind_passed,valgrind.log,$@)
```

and

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$($(PKG)-py-valgrind-tests-status): LOG-FILE = $$(subst valgrind_passed,valgrind.log,$@)
```

and(inside the recipe)

```
$(eval LOG-FILE = $$(subst valgrind_passed,valgrind.log,$@))
```

but for all, if I write

```
--log-file=$(LOG-FILE)
```

log file come's up empty.

I have no more ideas on how to go forward,
appreciate the help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using GNU make?  What version are you using (run `make --version`)?

There's nothing wrong with your first attempt, using a target-specific variable.  If this doesn't work then you've got something wrong or different about your makefile that you haven't explained.  Maybe if you showed the actual complete section of the makefile with the target-specific variable being set and used we might see what's wrong.

Your second attempt can't work because secondary expansion applies only the *prerequisites*, not target-specific variables (but, as above, it's not needed anyway).

Your third attempt might work but again, without seeing exactly what you do with the `eval` we can't say for sure.  You don't need to double the `$` before the `subst` function; it can be expanded first and it will still work.

Comment: I'm running 3.8.1

Comment: You mean 3.81.  There's no such version as 3.8.1.  Well, you'll have to provide an example with your actual attempt before we can know what's wrong, since as you've written it (broken out into two different parts) it seems correct.